# MySQL CASE with COUNT query

Tags: mysql

I asked a similar question before but I realized my desired output is totally different.

I have the following query

```
SELECT LEVEL, COUNT(*) AS total FROM admin_xxx
GROUP BY LEVEL ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 10
```

Table output

```
Level  Total
4       27
3       24
7       19
5       10
8       9
6       7
1       5
2       3
```

Now I just want to rename the actual level with words instead of numbers.

I would like to following as output

```
Level     Total
Bronze      27
Silver      24
Gold        19
Gold2       10
Gold3       9
Gold4       7
Gold5       5
Gold6       3
```

Each 10 levels have a separate level name.

I tried the following but get syntax error

```
SELECT LEVEL, COUNT(*) AS total FROM admin_xxx
CASE
WHEN LEVEL = 1 THEN "Bronze",
etc...
WHEN LEVEL = 10 THEN "Gold10"
  END as LEVEL

GROUP BY LEVEL ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: It should be easier with a simple join on a table that holds the level name with its id, and then group by level name. Plus this way your level names are not hardcoded into your sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have from clause in the wrong position

```
  SELECT 
      CASE
        WHEN LEVEL = 1 THEN "Bronze" 

        WHEN LEVEL = 10 THEN "Gold10"
      END as  LEVEL
    , COUNT(*) AS total 
  FROM admin_xxx
  GROUP BY LEVEL ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: I tried your code but got the following error: 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '
          WHEN LEVEL  = 10 THEN "Gold10"
        END as LEVEL' at line 3

Answer (score 0):

Change your `GROUP BY` to

```
GROUP BY (
    CASE
        WHEN LEVEL = 1 THEN "Bronze",
        etc...
        WHEN LEVEL = 10 THEN "Gold10"
    END
)
```

You also have syntax error on your `SELECT`

```
SELECT (
    CASE
        WHEN LEVEL = 1 THEN "Bronze",
        etc...
        WHEN LEVEL = 10 THEN "Gold10"
    END
) AS LEVEL
     , COUNT(*) AS total 
FROM admin_xxx
GROUP BY (
    CASE
        WHEN LEVEL = 1 THEN "Bronze",
        etc...
        WHEN LEVEL = 10 THEN "Gold10"
    END
)
ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: I tried your code but got the error: 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '
          WHEN LEVEL = 10 THEN "Gold10"
      END
  ) AS LEVEL
       , COUNT(*) AS' at line 3

Answer (score 0):

You can also separate yours levels/labels to another table, and you can join these.
For example:

```
SELECT levels.level_label, COUNT(*) AS total 
FROM admin_xxx
LEFT JOIN levels ON levels.label_value = admin_xxx.level
GROUP BY levels.level_label ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 10
```

And this is the levels table:

```
id  level_label     label_value
1   Bronze          10
2   Silver          9
3   Gold            1
4   Gold2           2
5   Gold3           3
6   Gold4           4
7   Gold5           5
8   Gold6           6
9   Gold7           7
10  Gold8           8
```

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THIS:** Obviously you should use `CASE` in the following way to achieve the desired output

```
SELECT CASE level 
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Bronze'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'Silver'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'Gold'
        WHEN 4 THEN 'Gold2'
        WHEN 5 THEN 'Gold3'
        WHEN 6 THEN 'Gold4'
        WHEN 6 THEN 'Gold5'
        WHEN 6 THEN 'Gold6'
        ELSE 'Unknown' END Level, 
    COUNT(*) AS total 
FROM admin_xxx
GROUP BY level 
ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 10
```